# CALayer renderInContext: Position of Drawing

Tags: core-animation, calayer, drawrect, cgcontext

I have a `UIView` with a custom shape drawn in `drawRect:`. The `frame` property is set to:

```
{5.f, 6.f, 50.f, 50.f}
```

Now, I render the view in an Image Context, but it is ignoring the frame property of the `UIView`, and always drawing the `UIView` in the top left.

```
[_shapeView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

I tried to change the `frame` of the `CALayer`, but nothing changed. Modifying the `bounds` property made things worse. The only work around I found useful was:

```
CGRect frame = _shapeView.frame;
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y);
[_shapeView.layer renderInContext:context];
```

But, this is impractical when I am dealing with many shapes, I want to just use the frame property.

Comment: That is expected to happen. Think of what it would mean if the opposite was true. Anyhow, try changing the origin of the `bounds` instead.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thanks, changing the bounds would cause the upper 6 px and left 5 px of the drawing to be sliced :( , ie doesn't work.

Comment: I discovered `CGContextDrawLayer` methods, which throw EXE_BAD_ACCESS when I try to use them.. I guess it's better to avoid those..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `CGContextTranslateCTM` is the proper way to go. As `renderInContext:` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410909-renderincontext) states : "Renders in the coordinate space of the layer." This means the frame origin of your layer/view is ignored.

Regarding `CGContextDrawLayer`, it is not made to be used with `CALayer`, but with `CGLayer`. These are two very different things, and explains your crash.

Comment: Great hint also for other modifications of the context before calling `-renderInContext:`! So the way is to prepare your context first and render to it afterwards.